# MongoDB and API integration - Create New User if Doesn't Already Exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to maintain a users table on MongoDB that contains extracts from our Slack channel that we can access from the Slack API. At the moment I am trying to check each time we load up the server, whether there are any new members of the channel and if so, create a new user.

Here is the script that currently tells me that all users Already Exist but my users table has only 1 entry at the moment and it should have created another 6 users.
`slack_data` is the results of the call to the slack api.

```
const Users = require('../models/users');
const _ = require('lodash');

function Database(){

}

Database.prototype.integration = function(slack_data){
  var jsonLength = Object.keys(slack_data).length;
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i <= jsonLength; i++) {
    if (Users.find({slack_id: slack_data.members[i].id}) != 'undefined'){
      console.log('User already exists');
    }
    else{
      Users.create({
        name: slack_data.members[i].real_name,
        slack_id: slack_data.members[i].id,
        slack_image: slack_data.members[i].profile.image_192,
        slack_image_48: slack_data.members[i].profile.image_48,
        slack_image_512: slack_data.members[i].profile.image_512
      })
      console.log(slack_data.members[i].real_name, " created");
    }
  }
}

module.exports = Database;
```

The actual console.log output I am getting is :

```
undefined
User already exists
User already exists
User already exists
User already exists
User already exists
```

This is again a bit odd as there are 7 user records in the Slack API.

The slack api structure looks like this:

```
{
ok: true,
members: [
{
id: "USLACKBOT",
team_id: "TCW7",
name: "slackbot",
deleted: false,
color: "757575",
real_name: "slackbot",
tz: null,
tz_label: "Pacific Daylight Time",
tz_offset: -25200,
profile: {
title: "",
phone: "",
skype: "",
real_name: "slackbot",
real_name_normalized: "slackbot",
display_name: "slackbot",
display_name_normalized: "slackbot",
fields: null,
status_text: "",
status_emoji: "",
status_expiration: 0,
avatar_hash: "sv1444671949",
always_active: true,
first_name: "slackbot",
last_name: "",
image_24: "https://a.slack-edge.com/0180/img/slackbot_24.png",
image_32: "https://a.slack-edge.com/7f1a0/plugins/slackbot/assets/service_32.png",
image_48: "https://a.slack-edge.com/7f1a0/plugins/slackbot/assets/service_48.png",
image_72: "https://a.slack-edge.com/0180/img/slackbot_72.png",
image_192: "https://a.slack-edge.com/66f9/img/slackbot_192.png",
image_512: "https://a.slack-edge.com/1801/img/slackbot_512.png",
status_text_canonical: "",
team: "TCW7"
},
is_admin: false,
is_owner: false,
is_primary_owner: false,
is_restricted: false,
is_ultra_restricted: false,
is_bot: false,
is_app_user: false,
updated: 0
},
```

Can you help me find out what is going wrong and suggest how I could perform the desired User creation?

### Edits Based on the selected answer below

**Using the Await option my code now looks like this:**

```
const Users = require('../models/users');
const _ = require('lodash');

function Database(){

}

Database.prototype.integration = async (slack_data) => {
  let newUsers = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < slack_data.members.length; i++) {
    const user = await Users.findOne({slack_id: slack_data.members[i].id});

    if (!user || typeof user.slack_id === 'undefined') {
      newUsers.push({
        name: slack_data.members[i].real_name,
        slack_id: slack_data.members[i].id,
        slack_image: slack_data.members[i].profile.image_192,
        slack_image_48: slack_data.members[i].profile.image_48,
        slack_image_512: slack_data.members[i].profile.image_512
      });
    };
  }

  const newSlackUsers = await Users.insertMany(newUsers);
  console.log('New users created ', newSlackUsers);
}

  module.exports = Database;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find()` method is asynchronous and there is no telling when these functions will complete, due to their asynchronous nature, or in what order they will complete when you place them in a for loop.

There are several ways of dealing with this. You can use the default Promise returned when you call `exec()` method on the `findOne()` or `find()` methods.

You can also embrace async/await in which the async function can be blocked by await/promise, therefore array iteration can be blocked until an await response.

Another option is to use an immediately-invoked-anonymous-function which ensures that the asynchronous functions get called with the correct value of the index variable.

Let's explore each option with examples.

**Using Promises**

```
const _ = require('lodash');

Database.prototype.integration = (slack_data) => {
    let userPromises = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < slack_data.members.length; i++) {
        const user = User.findOne({slack_id: slack_data.members[i].id}).lean().exec();
        userPromises.push(user);
    }

    Promise.all(userPromises).then(users => {
        const memberIds = slack_data.members.map(s => s.id);
        const slackIds = users.map(u => u.slack_id);
        const newUserIds = _.difference(slackIds, memberIds);

        const newUsers = newUserIds.map(id => {
            const member = _.find(slack_data.members, ['id', id]);
            return {
                name: member.real_name,
                slack_id: member.id,
                slack_image: member.profile.image_192,
                slack_image_48: member.profile.image_48,
                slack_image_512: member.profile.image_512 
            }
        );

        return User.insertMany(newUsers);
    }).then(newUsers => console.log('New users created ', newUsers));

}
```

**Using async/await**

```
Database.prototype.integration = async (slack_data) => {
    let newUsers = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < slack_data.members.length; i++) {
        const user = await User.findOne({slack_id: slack_data.members[i].id}).lean().exec();
        if (typeof user === 'undefined') {
            newUsers.push({
                name: slack_data.members[i].real_name,
                slack_id: slack_data.members[i].id,
                slack_image: slack_data.members[i].profile.image_192,
                slack_image_48: slack_data.members[i].profile.image_48,
                slack_image_512: slack_data.members[i].profile.image_512
            });
        };
    }

    const newSlackUsers = await User.insertMany(newUsers);
    console.log('New users created ', newSlackUsers);

}
```

**Using IIFE** (Immediately-Invoked-Function-Expression)

```
Database.prototype.integration = (slack_data) => {
    let newUsers = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < slack_data.members.length; i++) {
        (function(idx){
            User.indOne({ slack_id: slack_data.members[idx].id }, (err, user) => {
                if (typeof user === 'undefined') {
                    newUsers.push({
                        name: slack_data.members[idx].real_name,
                        slack_id: slack_data.members[idx].id,
                        slack_image: slack_data.members[idx].profile.image_192,
                        slack_image_48: slack_data.members[idx].profile.image_48,
                        slack_image_512: slack_data.members[idx].profile.image_512
                    });
                 };
            });
        }(i));
    }

    User.insertMany(newUsers, (err, newSlackUsers) => {
        console.log('New slack users created ', newSlackUsers);
    });
}
```

Comment: Wow - thank you so much for that fab reply. I will be able to refer to that for some time to help me finally grasp promises and how to handle them. 

I have tried all 3 methods suggested and haven't quite got it to work. I've edited my original question to show your very slightly amended code and the results I am getting. I've also shown the full file in case in case I'm causing the problem elsewhere.

Comment: Could I also ask about the insert method rather than the Create method. I assumed that while Create follows my schema and applies my validations and defaults, I suspect that insert wouldn't do that. Is that correct and if so is it possible to revise the code to use my Create function?

Comment: I've just got it to work using your await method. The problem seemed to be that the test for typeof user always returned object rather than undefined or was null which then resulted in the uncatched error message. I changed the test to if (!user || typeof user.slack_id === 'undefined') and that is now working as I wanted. Thanks so much.

Comment: @whatapalaver Glad you got it to work but had made a mistake with the await, it's supposed to be `const user = await User.findOne({slack_id: slack_data.members[i].id}).lean().exec();` i.e. use the `lean()` method on `findOne` to return a plain JS object and then chain `exec()` method to return a promise

Comment: I’ve never seen lean() before. I’ll check it tomorrow - thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong in **find**

```
User.findOne({slack_id: slack_data.members[i].id})
        .then((user) => {
          if (user) {
             console.log('User already exists');
          } else {
              //Create new User.
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          //handle Error
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I haven't quite got it to work yet though. I've revised according to your suggestion. Unfortunately there is not enough space in a comment to show you. I am attempting to pull the json length using object.keys(slack_data).length but I've just noticed this is incorrect as it gives me the higher level keys and not the members length. If I put the length of the members by either Object.keys(slack_data.members).length or just forcing it to 7, I then get undefined console message. 

As the code stands it does create users but it creates duplicates - See next comment

Comment: Here's the current console.log:
Tim B  created
Tim B  created
UCYK2L  already exists
UCYK2L  already exists
UCYK2L  already exists

Comment: Database.prototype.integration = function(slack_data){
      var jsonLength = Object.keys(slack_data).length
      for (var i = 0; i <= jsonLength; i++) {
        Users.findOne({slack_id: slack_data.members[i].id})
          .then((user) => {
            if (user) {
              console.log(slack_data.members[i].id, ' already exists');
            } else {
                Users.create({
                ..
                })
                console.log(slack_data.members[i].real_name, " created");
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {

Comment: Sorry that is totally illegible - I'm not sure if I can post code snippets in comments.